# Command that takes info from FiveM

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, fivem

I would like to build a command , in Node.js with Visual Studio Code, which will take data from FiveM and will show in a message how many players are online and if there is a Queue !

I will post an image and I will show what i mean: [image]

I am using a code that logs in console and the code is :

```
const Gamedig = require('gamedig');
Gamedig.query({
    type: 'fivem',
    host: 'fivem.example.com'
}).then((state) => {
    console.log(state);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Server is offline");
});
```

I would like to ask if there is a way to set as command and display "image" view!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [gamedig documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gamedig), the `state` param that is going in the callback function have not that much predefined properties. You can retrieve directly how many players are online by the `players.length` property, accessing it by `state.players.length` inside the callback function in the `then()` method. But there's too a `raw` property which seems to return all the info the server gives you back, so you can try to parse it and retrieve any other relevant info.

Comment: It returns me all the time Server is Offline and the server is online !

`}).then((state) => {
    console.log(state.players.length);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Server is offline");
});`

Comment: Problably there's something about the server link or the way the bib works itself. Can you share the server link so we can try it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [FiveM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fivem) package to get server info.

You can get the players like this:

```js
    const FiveM = require("fivem") // Import the npm package.
    const srv = new FiveM.Server('IP:PORT') // Set the IP with port.
    srv.getPlayers().then(data => console.log(data)) // Get & log the data!
```

or the whole server object:

```js
    srv.getServer().then(data => console.log(data)) // Get & log the data!
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you very much . This code is working as a want . You are awesome !

Comment: No problem. You can use the green check on this post to mark it as the answer so others know.

Comment: I would do that but i asked for help to build a command not console logs.